# one item of the list in xml data

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have this code: and i want to when i do the query to print one field in xml file.

I mean print only the field "Name"

How can i do that?

thanks

c#:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var name = textBox3.Text;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"data.xml");

            var xpath = "//*[text()= ' " + name + "']";

            var result = ((IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate(xpath)).Cast<XElement>().FirstOrDefault();
            var storeElement = doc.Descendants("store").Where(e => e.Attribute("rollNumer").Value == name).First();
            textBox1.Text = storeElement.Value;

        }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<stores>
  <store rollNumer="170">
    <Name>Jonh</Name>
    <Color>Pink</Color>
    <Sell>Sugar</Sell>
  </store>

  <store rollNumer="120">
    <Name>Tedy</Name>
    <Color>Brown</Color>
    <Sell>Rice</Sell>
  </store>
</stores>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

For your real scenario, just uncomment the `.Load()` method, and comment out the `.Parse()` method.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string inputFile = @"e:\Temp\data.xml";
    //XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(inputFile);
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<stores>
      <store rollNumer='170'>
        <Name>Jonh</Name>
        <Color>Pink</Color>
        <Sell>Sugar</Sell>
      </store>

      <store rollNumer='120'>
        <Name>Tedy</Name>
        <Color>Brown</Color>
        <Sell>Rice</Sell>
      </store>
    </stores>");

    XElement helem = xdoc.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault();
    string output = helem .Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope will help you

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(inputFile);
string storeElement = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("store"))
{
    if (item.Attribute("rollNumer").Value == name)
    {
        storeElement = item.Descendants("Name").First().Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create classes to represent your data in terms of the problem you are solving. After that, once you have loaded it into your program, you can think about it in terms of the problem you are working on and it is easier because you abstracted away low level details in this case about xml.

```cs
    
    public class DataExtractor
    {
        public string GetPropertyValue(string rollNumber)
        {
            var filename = "InputData.xml";

            XmlSerializer serializer =
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(stores));

            stores data;

            using (Stream reader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                data = (stores)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            var result = data.store.Where(s => s.rollNumer.Equals(rollNumber)).Select(n => n.Name).FirstOrDefault();

            return result;
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class stores
    {

        private storesStore[] storeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement("store")]
        public storesStore[] store
        {
            get
            {
                return this.storeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.storeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [Serializable()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class storesStore
    {

        private string nameField;

        private string colorField;

        private string sellField;

        private string rollNumerField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Color
        {
            get
            {
                return this.colorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.colorField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Sell
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sellField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sellField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string rollNumer
        {
            get
            {
                return this.rollNumerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.rollNumerField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```